# How do i add "timezone list" (dropdown) to the google's FullCalendar?

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

As am new to the google's [full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/) API, i need some help...
I want to add the Dorpdown list of timezone's to the fullCalendar, After selecting the particular timezone from that list, all times in the calendar must be convert as per the timezone selected.

My jQuery code :

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: false,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'year,agendaDay,agendaWeek,month,prevYear,nextYear'
    },
    editable: false,
    events:<?php echo $event_str; ?>,
    ignoreTimezone: false
});
```

Please suggest me if am going with wrong logic for timezone selection.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of fullcalendar are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Got the exact answer [here](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-2.0.0-beta2/demos/timezones.html) which am looking for

Its present in the new version of full Calendar. 
Hope my own answer will help someone.